# Rewards on private network

Tags: smart-contract, nodeos

I want to have rewards mechanism in private network with two bps how can I do that? is there any way to modify current reward mechanism ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything on system contract. If you want reward for 2 BPs, just change bps number to 2.

More detail, you can check eos/contracts/eosio.system/producer_pay.cpp

Comment: instead of yearly basis i want pay producers daily basis is there any way @Quoc Le

Comment: Of course, You can. Currently, in 5% annual inflation there are 4% for work propose system and 1% for block reward. If you provide more details what you want, i can hep ...